# Ehcache as JCache Implementation configured in Spring

Tags: java, spring, ehcache, jcache

I am trying to use the following jcache-ehcache library to as a wrapper so that I can use Ecache as my JCache implementation.

These are my maven dependancies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache-jcache</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0-beta1</version>
    </dependency>
```

In my Spring configuration file, I have the following beans:

```
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="shared" value="true"/>
</bean>


<bean id="userCache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean">
    <property name="cacheName" value="userCache"/>
    <property name="cacheManager" ref="cacheManager"/>
    <property name="diskPersistent" value="false"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jcacheUserCache" class="net.sf.ehcache.jcache.JCache">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="userCache"/>
</bean>
```

And my Ehcache.xml (on classpath root) file contains the userCache region definition:

```
  <cache name="userCache" maxElementsInMemory="10000"
  maxElementsOnDisk="0" eternal="false" overflowToDisk="false"
  diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="20" timeToIdleSeconds="0"
  timeToLiveSeconds="0" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU"
  statistics = "true">
  </cache>
```

On initialization, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jcacheUserCache' defined in class path resource [application-context.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 1 of type [net.sf.ehcache.jcache.JCacheManager]: Ambiguous constructor argument types - did you specify the correct bean references as constructor arguments?
```

Can anyone provide any assistance with how to correctly initialise this `jCacheUserCache` bean?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor of `net.sf.ehcache.jcache.JCache` has three arguments, but you only provided the first one when creating the `jcacheUserCache` bean. The error you get is about the missing second parameter (of type `net.sf.ehcache.jcache.JCacheManager`).

The constructor of `JCache` looks like this:

```
public JCache(Ehcache ehcache, JCacheManager cacheManager, ClassLoader classLoader) {
    // ...
}
```

So you also need to provide a `JCacheManager` and a `ClassLoader` as constructor arguments.

(see [`JCache.java` here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache-jcache/1.4.0-beta1/net/sf/ehcache/jcache/JCache.java?av=f))

Comment: Hmm - I was looking at the wrong api- these package names are very similiar!